# SoundTouch Class Example

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've some classes and I'm trying to call a function of a class from main swf. But I'm getting error 1120. Here's my main fla:

```
import PlayerClass;

SimplePlayer.play(Sound1);
```

Edit:
I've found an example but now I'm still getting error.

```
var source:Sound = new Sound1();
var output:Sound = new Sound();

var soundTouch:SoundTouch = new SoundTouch();
soundTouch.pitchSemitones = -6;

var filter:SimpleFilter = new SimpleFilter(sound, soundTouch);
output.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, filter.handleSampleData);

output.play();
```

This gives me error:

```
Sahne 1, Katman ‘Katman 1’, Kare 1, Satır 18, Sütun 44  1120: sound tanımlanmamış özelliğinin erişimi.
```

When I try:

```
var source:Sound = new Sound1();
var output:Sound = new Sound();

var soundTouch:SoundTouch = new SoundTouch();

output.play();
```

I'm getting this error

```
ArgumentError: Error #2068: Invalid sound.
    at flash.media::Sound/play()
    at Adsız_08_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

The class source is here: https://github.com/also/soundtouch-as3

Comment: There's not enough information to help you. Perhaps you should first turn to documentation of your library (if it's not you who wrote it). Also, if SimplePlayer is an instance of SoundChannel, you can simply find info on playing sounds on the web. Anyway, from what you wrote it's not clear what you're doing and what you want.

Comment: Even if Creative Magic is right, what i can say to help you is that 1120 is a compiler Error about a undefined property in your code. It should gave you the line and if it is the one you put in the Question than could be "SimplePlayer" or "Sound1"

Comment: Tell us what's written on line 44

Comment: line 18: var filter:SimpleFilter = new SimpleFilter(sound, soundTouch);

column 44: sound

Comment: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/335615/

Answer (score 0):

All you do in every single cases is trying to play an empty sound:

```
var output:Sound = new Sound();//this is an empty sound
output.play();//nothing to play so error
```

You need to follow a tutorial on how to play a sound in Actionscript 3. I believe the Actionscript 3 docs have a fully working example. I suggest to start there.